# Javascript continues to encode my uri snippet even with decodeURI

Tags: javascript, encoding

I have a very simple javascript snippet on my webpages. It is only one line of code but using it with the javascript on my other pages allows me to redirect a direct link to a child page to the same page but contained within the frame I have set.

```
self.location.pathname = decodeURI("beginpage.asp?Programs/Programs.asp");
self.location.pathname = decodeURIComponent("beginpage.asp?Programs/Programs.asp");
self.location.pathname = decodeURI("beginpage.asp%3FPrograms/Programs.asp");
self.location.pathname = decodeURIComponent("beginpage.asp%3FPrograms/Programs.asp");
```

All of these I have tried and I still get the encoding of '?' as %3F in the url. Basically, it comes out like this `pignet/beginpage.asp%3FPrograms/Programs.asp`

Comment: Are you sure? The last one, decodeURIComponent works for me. https://jsfiddle.net/g9xqqawb/

Comment: Yeah, tried it again. Still doesn't work. When I try to set the pathname it still comes out as %3F.

Comment: Can we see the rest of the code?

Answer (score 0):

The below works out fine for me.

decodeURIComponent("beginpage.asp%3FPrograms/Programs.asp");